# Header-only C++ INTERFACE library shows linker error in the second dependent CMake project

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

**myapp** - executable

**mylib1** - library with source and headers

**mylib2** - header-only library

This is my dependency chain,

```
myapp -> mylib1 -> mylib2
```

mylib2 compiles fine (checked with tests)

mylib1 compiles fine

myapp compilation fails with the error

```
Target "myapp" links to target "mylib2::mylib2" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

When I use `target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE mylib2)`. I am error free!
But I want to contain mylib2 inside mylib1

mylib2's CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(mylib2 INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(mylib2 INTERFACE
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)
```

mylib1's CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(mylib2)
add_library(mylib1 ${mylib1_SOURCES})
target_include_directories(mylib1 PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)
target_link_libraries(mylib1 PUBLIC mylib2) #lib2 holds some important structs that i need to use in myapp
```

And finally myapp's CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(mylib1)
add_executable(myapp app.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE mylib1)
```

In myapp's CMakeLists.txt, when I add the following line. CMake runs without any error

```
find_package(mylib2)
# note there is no target_link_libraries(myapp mylib2)
```

But without the above line, I get the CMake error mentioned at the start. I proceed to use `make` on the error-configured cmake build folder. I get the following error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmylib2::mylib2
```

But linker should not run on mylib2, it's a header only library.
Why should I include `find_package(mylib2)` in myapp. Someone help me understand this issue.

Comment: Because the project for `mylib1` library uses `find_package(mylib1)`, **configuration file** (`mylib1Config.cmake`) created by this project should contain `find_dependency(mylib1)` call. More detailed example see in the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-a-package-configuration-file) about the packaging.

Comment: Do you mean `find_package(mylib2)` and `find_dependency(mylib2)`

Comment: @Tsyvarev Your solution worked, thank you so much! I have been searching this for over a year now!

Comment: Can the solution that 'Tsyvarev' sketched here please be written as a fully fledged answer. I have a similar problem, and would like to see what the fully qualified solution is now